# cannot get file to upload in PhP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have added this to my form_action.php:

```
if(isset($_FILES['attachment1'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['attachment1']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['attachment1']['size'];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['attachment1']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['attachment1']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","doc","pdf");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, PNG, PDF or DOC file.";
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
}
```

with the form field being

```
<form method="post" action="form_action1.php">
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="attachment1">Add file(s)</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment1" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment1">
     <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment2" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment2">
     <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment3" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="attachment3">       
 </div>
</form>
```

The path gets saved but the file does not upload. Am I missing a step that I am not aware of? Also, can I set an ARRAY in the $_FILES field to allow for three uploads?

This is the last step in a personal project that I am trying to complete. Thank you.

Comment: include the full form

Comment: What do you mean "the paths get saved"?  I see no code that "saves the path" anywhere.  And this could be simplified `if ( empty( $errors ) == TRUE ) ` to simply `if ( ! $errors ) {`....

Comment: Did you add `enctype`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yup no `enctype` now go answer for cheap points

Comment: @cale_b thank you. I did not know about the file path @Preveen I did not know about `code`enctype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `enctype` for the form to post files.

```
<form method="post" action="form_action1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype):

> **`enctype`**
>
> When the value of the method attribute is post, enctype is the MIME type of content that is used to submit the form to the server. Possible values are:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded: The default value if the attribute is not specified.
>
> - `multipart/form-data:` The value used for an  element with the type attribute set to "file".
> - `text/plain` (HTML5): This value can be overridden by a formenctype attribute on a  or  element.

Comment: ACtually, this did not work. Could it be because I added this to my whole PhP actions file?

Comment: @SeanRawles How did you add? Everything looks correct for me.

Comment: Also, honestly, why did this get a down vote? Is it not okay to ask questions?

Comment: @SeanRawles It was put when the necessary info wasn't there. I didn't downvote BTW.

Comment: added it to my form action that also writes to the SQL table

Comment: And don't worry, downvote here doesn't cause you any issue.

Comment: @SeanRawles You aren't using `attachment2` and `attachment3` in your code?

Comment: Does this step fail? `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);`?

Comment: @SeanRawles Do you have a place to show the working code? Like lets say, c9.io?

Comment: @SeanRawles Ah... Before the success echo, give a mysql update query.

Comment: yeah. No idea how to do that. Again - trying to learn :D I am sure I will get it.

Comment: @SeanRawles Waiting for your new question, so that let's see how we can discuss.

Comment: I can only post a question every 90 minutes.

Comment: @SeanRawles Okay, post later and ping me.